# Is it possible to install msys2 in windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, msys2

Is it possible to install msys2 in windows 7 home edition?

[image]

Comment: I think they dropped Win 7 support. Why not update to a newer OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last release whose full installer supports Windows 7 is here. Just click on "Assets" then download the full installer.

https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/tag/2022-10-28

Comment: this helped me ! Tks!

Answer (score 4):

Very easy. All you need is to download *archive*, not installer.

https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-i686-latest.tar.xz (32-bit)

https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.tar.xz (64-bit)

Then you should unpack it. Default location is `c:\msys64`

If it needs some `api-ms-win-` libs, then you can download them from here:

https://github.com/huangqinjin/ucrt